# How do I get Gmail to wrap my paragraph text in the default HTML mode?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, email, google-workspace-for-business

I've been noticing of late that when I write paragraphs that end up needing  word-wrapping as Gmail will make these lines extremely long and cause horizontal scroll bars and hence make having to read the email very annoying.

I have done some testing and most clients will keep it this way and hence cause issues for the receiver; however, I noticed **Thunderbird** wraps long lines nicely.

I have tried sending the exact same message from Thunderbird and it wraps the lines nicely (I have the format on `auto-detect`).

I can't use `plain-text` mode as I have a HTML signature included; is there a fix for this? Surely there must be a fix for this for such a large email provider?

I am using **GSuite** (formerly Google Apps) if it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems it wasn't a Gmail issue at all; it was caused by my email signature.

I had set my HTML email signature to 100%, such as…

```
<table width="100%" style="width: 100% !important;">
```

so this was what was creating a long page width and the text was just utilising the space already created; I removed the `width` parameters and everything looks great!