# How do you make all incoming Gmail's wrap?

Tags: gmail

I've noticed that in Gmail some incoming emails do not word wrap. This is quite annoying as I have to navigate the cursor horizontally to read the message. None of the suggested methods are ergonomic as they still force you to zoom or scroll. Any ideas on how to force incoming Gmail's to wrap automatically?

Comment: Related: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/27347/88163

Comment: This is such a PIA.  Many suggested fixes either 1.) don't work for me, 2) apply to *outgoing* mail, 3) suggest ideas that don't exist.  And then problems that seemingly only I have, e.g. Gmail cuts off the right side of everything, so any links there are not usable.  Only work-around for me:  Reply (still cut off, shift-reply does nothing), Window key - left arrow (maximizes reply window on the left side of screen, right-side buttons are now visible),  Shift-reply to pop out.     Question: how do you navigate the cursor horizontally?  There is no scroll bar (as you undoubtedly know).

Answer (score 2):

May or may not be helpful, but one workaround I've found is to hit Reply or Forward, then you can edit the text in the message you've received, ie insert enter/carriage return functions to drop the unseen text to the next line etc. Enough for you to be able to see what you can't anyway.
I've done that to be able to print some messages.
Not a solution I know, but helpful until Google fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything automatic; it's a pain. I do:

- Click on the upper-right menu in the message you received.
- Select 'show original'.
- You get the raw text, including headers, etc. Scroll down.

Thiis is not so great for emails that have lots of images, etc. But you just want the text. The alternative is to cut and paste into a text editor.

I looked at a raw message. The text *should* be on a single line: it's coded as a single object with '='s joining the raw lines. Gmail does the correct thing.
It's the sender's client that creates the "problem". Though it would be nice if gmail had a right-click option to explicitly split/wrap a string object...

Comment: "Click on the upper-right menu in the message you received." What do you mean? Show a picture, please - as I cannot find 'show original' option... (On my PC, some text continues off screen to the right - most annoying!)